Checking empty string not working in loop
Hi I am new to programming and java.
The below code is going to be adding the user inputs into a file which I have not implemented yet. However,
I don't know why:

The checking of the empty string (the displaying of the 'Error. Please enter a name.' message) only works when the outer do-while loop is not present, but the checking of the time works.
I also put the name = "";
time = -1.0;
at the start of the do-while loop again to restart the variables since the input for the name would get skipped over since it has a string already from the first time the code is run, but is there another way to restart the variables properly or to improve my empty string checking so i don't have to do this roundabout method?

Would appreciate any help.
package so;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class programTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = "";
    double time = -1.0;
    char moreDataChoice = 'a';
    boolean moreData = true;

    do {
      name = "";
      time = -1.0;

      System.out.println("Name:");
      while (name.isEmpty() == true) {
        name = sc.next();

        if (name.isEmpty() == false) {
          break;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Error. Please enter a name.");
        }
      }

      System.out.println("Time:");
      do {
        time = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();
        if (time > 0) {
          break;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Error. Please enter a appropriate time");
        }
      } while (time < 0.0);

      System.out.println("Enter more data? (y/n)");
      do {
        moreDataChoice = sc.next().charAt(0);


        if (moreDataChoice == 'y') {
          moreData = true;
        } else if (moreDataChoice == 'n') {
          moreData = false;
          break;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Error. Please enter y or n.");
        }

      } while ((moreDataChoice != 'y') && (moreDataChoice != 'n'));
    } while (moreData == true);
    sc.close();
  }
}


The checking of the empty string (the displaying of the 'Error. Please enter a name.' message) only works when the outer do-while loop is not present, but the checking of the time works.
I also put the name = "";
time = -1.0;
at the start of the do-while loop again to restart the variables since the input for the name would get skipped over since it has a string already from the first time the code is run, but is there another way to restart the variables properly or to improve my empty string checking so i don't have to do this roundabout method?


What is the teamName variable? I don't see it declared anywhere

Sorry I was changing the variable names when i put it here and forgot to change that, the teamName is supposed to be name. In my code it is name and not teamName

Okay. And is there any error or problem in your code? or do you just need a better way to restart the variables?
And If you are anyways resetting the variables, why do you have to check whether it's empty or not?

While I would like to know a better way to restart the variables, the main problem I have is that it does not check/display the error message when the user enters an empty string. I have not done this part of the code yet but the reset is done since all the user inputs will be added to a file. Sorry for the trouble, thank you for letting me know what I missed out on explaining the code

So, when a user enters a empty string, you want to show the error message and then let them re-enter the name?

Yep! Thats the idea i was going for

NB name.isEmpty() == true: don't compare things are are already Boolean to booleans. name.isEmpty() is sufficient, and !name.isEmpty() for name.isEmpty() == false.

The below code uses separate methods for obtaining the name and the time – just to show you a different way to code your program.
Note that method nextDouble, in class Scanner, will throw InputMismatchException if the entered value cannot be parsed to a double. Beginner programmers tend to assume that user-entered values will always be valid. Nonetheless, you should always add code that handles invalid input. Also, InputMismatchException is an unchecked exception which means it doesn't need to be explicitly handled, but it can be. Consequently, you may want to re-consider what constitutes a valid name – apart from it not being empty. Currently any sequence of characters is a valid name, for example $#3.14?
Lastly, after calling method nextDouble and before calling method nextLine, you need to add [another] call to method nextLine. Refer to this SO question to understand why.
Here is the code:
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgTest {

    private static String getName(Scanner sc) {
        String name;
        do {
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("You did not enter a name.");
            }
        } while (name.isEmpty());
        return name;
    }

    private static double getTime(Scanner sc) {
        double time;
        do {
            System.out.print("Time: ");
            try {
                time = sc.nextDouble();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException xInput) {
                time = 0.0;
            }
            if (time <= 0.0) {
                System.out.println("Enter a positive number (which may include a decimal fraction).");
            }
            sc.nextLine();
        } while (time <= 0);
        return time;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice;
        do {
            String name = getName(sc);
            double time = getTime(sc);
            System.out.printf("Received: %s %f%n", name, time);
            System.out.print("Enter more data? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.nextLine();
        } while ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(choice));
    }
}

Here is output from a run of the above code:
Name: 
You did not enter a name.
Name: George
Time: d
Enter a positive number (which may include a decimal fraction).
Time: 0
Enter a positive number (which may include a decimal fraction).
Time: 5.9
Received: George 5.900000
Enter more data? (y/n): y
Name: Diego
Time: 10
Received: Diego 10.000000
Enter more data? (y/n): n


Thank you so much for the help!! As a beginner programmer, it is hard for me to think of things in methods so this is very helpful. I actually came into another separate problem and it would be very appreciated if you could also help me on this. I posted it here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78402657/java-only-last-input-gets-written-in-file-previous-inputs-ignored).

First of all, I felt like you have too many do-while loops for no good reason. I have modified your code to make it more simpler and since you have to get input from user every time, you don't need to reset the variables. You can always get the input, then check whether it is empty or not, and then prompt them to enter again.
Also changed code in some places where you were using sc.next for sc.nextLine which you could understand if you look at the code.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = "";
    double time = -1.0;
    char moreDataChoice = 'y';
    boolean moreData = true;

    while(moreDataChoice == 'y') {
      System.out.print("Name:");
      name = sc.nextLine();
      while (name.isEmpty()) {
          System.out.println("Error. Please enter a name.");
          name = sc.nextLine();
      }

      System.out.println("Time:");
      time = sc.nextDouble();
      sc.nextLine();
      while(time < 0.0) {
         System.out.println("Error. Please enter a appropriate time");
         time = sc.nextDouble();
         sc.nextLine();
      }

      System.out.println("Enter more data? (y/n)");
      moreDataChoice = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
      
      while(!(moreDataChoice == 'y' || moreDataChoice == 'n')) {
          System.out.println("Error. Please enter y or n.");
          moreDataChoice = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
      }  
    }
    System.out.println("Program ended");
    sc.close();
  }
}


Thank you for so much the help! The code definitely looks more organized now. However, during the first iteration of the program after the name and time has been entered for the first time, it ignores the user input for name and instead the output is as follows:
Name:
Error. Please enter a name.
So the error message is displayed when the user hasn't made an error? and only that error message is displayed the user is permitted to input the name again

@natadecoco Not sure when that's happening. Works fine for me in my local
