(Java) Only last input gets written in file, previous inputs ignored
I'm having trouble making the code to write multiple lines to the CSV file. When I open up the CSV file, only the last input by the user is shown and all the previous inputs are not.
I also can't seem to put the headers at the top of the file to show "Name, Time"
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class programOneTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice;
        do
        {
            String fileName = "storage.csv";
            String name = getName(sc);
            double time = getTime(sc);
            writeToFile(fileName, name, time);
            System.out.println("Would you like to enter more data? (Y/N)");
            choice = sc.nextLine();

        } while ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(choice));
    }

    private static String getName(Scanner sc)
    {
        String name;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Name:");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            if (name.isEmpty()) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error. Please enter a name.");
            }
        } while (name.isEmpty());
        return name;
    }

    private static double getTime(Scanner sc)
    {
        double time = -1.0;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Time:");
            time = sc.nextDouble();
            sc.nextLine();
            if (time > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error. Please enter an appropriate time.");
            }
            
        } while (time < 0);
        return time;
    }

    private static void writeToFile(String pFileName, String pName, double pTime)
    {
        FileOutputStream fileStrm = null;
        PrintWriter pw;
        try
        {
            fileStrm = new FileOutputStream(pFileName);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fileStrm);
                        pw.println("Name , Time"); //Apparently i cannot do this as it causes errors?
            pw.println(pName + "," + pTime);
            pw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in writing to file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

Output in program:
Name:
John
Time:
6
Would you like to enter more data? (Y/N)
Y
Name: 
Van
Time:
4

What is shown in CSV file:
Van, 4

What I want to be shown in CSV file:
Name, Time
John, 6
Van, 4


Does this answer your question? How to write data with FileOutputStream without losing old data?

Also, make sure all your data is read:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

check the documentation of the two-argument constructor of FileOutputStream

Thank you guys for the help, did not know a documentation exists holy

You should open the file with append flag "true"
fileStrm = new FileOutputStream(pFileName, true);

Reference to the documentation

Thank you so much omg I did not know a documentation exists

When you create a new PrintWriter, it creates a new, empty file. That's why only the last entry is saved in your file. I suggest using NIO.2 – which is available since Java 7 (which was released in 2011). Following code demonstrates.
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgTest {

    private static String getName(Scanner sc) {
        String name;
        do {
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("You did not enter a name.");
            }
        } while (name.isEmpty());
        return name;
    }

    private static double getTime(Scanner sc) {
        double time;
        do {
            System.out.print("Time: ");
            try {
                time = sc.nextDouble();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException xInput) {
                time = 0.0;
            }
            if (time <= 0.0) {
                System.out.println("Enter a positive number (which may include a decimal fraction).");
            }
            sc.nextLine();
        } while (time <= 0);
        return time;
    }

    private static void writeToFile(BufferedWriter bw, String line) throws IOException {
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice;
        Path path = Paths.get("storage.csv");
        try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path,
                                                         StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                         StandardOpenOption.APPEND,
                                                         StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
            writeToFile(bw, "Name,Time");
            do {
                String name = getName(sc);
                double time = getTime(sc);
                writeToFile(bw, name + "," + time);
                System.out.print("Enter more data? (y/n): ");
                choice = sc.nextLine();
            } while ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(choice));
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

